# Print message condition every 10 values

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to print a message, every 10 values if a condition is true in an array.

Example: user have the opportunity to log how many rows of 10 the user wanna type.

ex: 4.

then, user can type 20 values into array.

1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
so on...

now i need that under every 10 values, verify: if some of the following condition are satisfied:

```
if 2 == "mack".
if 3 == "rack".
if 3 && 2 == "both".
if aren't nay of the values = "none".
```

ex:

user log:

```
      1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 5
      1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 0 9
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
      1 2 0 0 5 6 7 8 9 0
```

Console show:

```
  1 2 4 5 6 7 8 9 0 5
      mack
      1 2 3 5 6 7 8 9 0 9
      rack
      1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
      both
      1 2 0 0 5 6 7 8 9 0
      none
```

how can i make this works>?

this i what i have till now:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num = sc.nextInt();

        int total = num * 10;

        int[] val = new int[total];

        for(int i = 0; i < val.length; i++)
        {
            val[i] = sc.nextInt();
        }
        int zack = 17;
        int mack = 18;

        int count = 0;
        String m = null;
        String r = null;

        String ans;

        for(int i = 0; i < val.length; i++)
        {
            System.out.print(val[i] + " ");

            count++;

            if(contains(val, 17))
            {
                ans = "zack";
            }
            else if(contains(val, 18))
            {
                ans = "mack";
            }
            else {
                ans = "none";
            }

            if(count == 10)
            {
                System.out.println();
                System.out.println(ans);


                count = 0;
            }
        }

    }
     static boolean contains(int[] arr, int item) {
          for (int n : arr) {
             if (item == n) {
                return true;
             }
          }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: please show your actual code! what you posted never outputs "rack"...

Comment: Seems like a variation of the FizzBuzz question (https://www.google.com/search?q=fizz+buzz). Do you want us to code it for you (http://examples.oreilly.com/jenut/FizzBuzz.java) or are your facing a specific problem?

Comment: @ccjmne Looks like a homework question to me, as you say a fizzbuzz variant. Cohen if you are stuck on a specific part then ask about that, we won't write it all for you though and right now that's what you are asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's pseudocode for what you want to do:

```
index = 0
twoSeen = false
threeSeen = false
for each item {
   if (item == 2) {
      twoSeen = true
   }
   if (item == 3) {
      threeSeen = true
   }
   print(item)
   index = index + 1
   if (index == 10) {
      printReport(twoSeen,threeSeen)
      index = 0
      twoSeen = false
      threeSeen = false
   }
}
```

All you need to do is translate this into Java, and write the `printReport` method (which should be trivial).

```
 private void printReport(boolean seen2, boolean seen3) {
      if(seen2 && !seen3) {
           System.out.println("Mack");
      } else if(...
```

... you can fill in the rest.

There is a smarter way to detect every tenth item using the `%` operator, but leave that until you have working code.

Note I have provided pseudocode and a partial answer because this looks like a homework question, so what you need is nudges in the right direction.

Comment: where's printreport method?

Comment: that's not what i'm asking about. i need with srtings, no booleans, where's "both" "none" option?  @slim

Comment: @cohen I deliberately left `printreport` as an "exercise for the reader". if you can't write a method that takes two booleans as input, and prints different things depending on whether one, the other, neither or both are true, then you need to do some basic learning about programming before using Stack Overflow. Hint: use "if" and potentially  "else".

Comment: @ slim. what you had posted, that really no help me "anything" , cuz i'm posting a problem to get 4 kinda of strings every 10 values, & you're posting a boolean & things, that i don't evn know where you took that from.

Comment: @cohen I have filled in some extra details, but this is WAY more basic stuff than SO is intended for. Get an introductory programming book.

Comment: Thanks so much. that was what i  was expecting :)